# Ubuntu to Ubuntu remote access using Remmina

Tags: vnc, remmina

I want to connect from my Ubuntu 22.04 computer to a remote Ubuntu 22.04 computer using Remmina. I have these settings:

[image]

However, when I click "save and connect" I get this:

[image]

How can I connect to my remote computer using Remmina?

Comment: Is your server using RDP or VNC? Try RDP.

Comment: If I select RDP, it there is no error but the remote connection window pops up and automatically closes after one second. So still not working. Isn't RDP only for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by changing to RDP, as suggested by @FedKad in the comment, and on top of this disabling and re-enabling the "Remote Desktop" option in the remote machine. Now it works.